# django - different save methods for user actions and admin action

Tags: django

I have some items connected to users.

When every item is added, timestamp is created through inheritance of BaseModel on auto_now field.

By mistake when i added new field and populated i updated timestamps.

I resolved timestamps with some custom migrations and copy data methods in django.

What i wonder - is there possibility to override save method on admin to do only update_fields (so in other words with that i would not update update_at timestamp),
while on user actions i want to retain original django save method which would update timestamp.

So basically is it possible to have two different save methods?

I know that i can override save method - but i don't know if i can have two save methods at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelAdmin.save_model() might deliver that for you.  Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).  Within your admin file, override the save_model function

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save(update_fields = ['fields', 'to', 'save'])
```

From looking at the django github, the [super of save_model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/41e8931c2cc68d8b2de4219be930e2c305b4eba1/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1222) doesn't do much more than call `obj.save()`, so I don't think you need or want to call super() in this case.

Comment: yup, i was aware of this, but wasn't aware if its gonna influence save method. But after testing, seems that it works. Thanks